# Cant connect to MongoDB by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, mlab

I have created a MongoDB account at mlab, but I cant seem to connect to it. It fails with the credentials. I cant seem to figure out, what I does wrong, besides it maybe is the connection string. Problem is, that I got that from Mlab (have added it here, but without the right user and password)

Thanks in advance

```
Dim connstring As String = "mongodb://USER:PASS@ds021239.mlab.com:22234"
        Dim mongo As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create(connstring)
        mongo.Connect()
        Dim mydatabase As MongoDatabase = mongo.GetDatabase("profundo", SafeMode.True)
        Dim collection = mydatabase.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Client")
        MsgBox(collection.Count)
```

Comment: What do you mean by can't connect? Any error message you get?  I'd suggest to update your post with related information

Comment: Try this for connection string: `"mongodb://USER:PASS@ds021239.mlab.com:22234/profundo"` This is the standard format: **mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@host:port/dbname**. Also please see documentation of what you are doing it helps [**here**](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/c%23/CSharpSimpleExample.cs)

Comment: Thanks. It worked :-)